# Highlighting the entire row based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want the entire row to be highlighted Yellow when the Cell I1, I2, I3  etc.. is 1

or

the entire row to be highlighted Green when the Cell I1, I2, I3 is 0

anyone can help with the VBA coding, what should the VBA coding be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA with Conditional Formats.

E. g.:
Mark entire Rows from 1:10 (just an example).

Set up the conditional format to
`=$I1=1`
and set the background color for this format.
This will instantly work on all rows 1 to 10 in column I.
(you need to add a rule for each value/color).

EDIT:
Conditional Formats can be copied/applied through VBA as well. The disadvantage of VBA firing on every cell change is that it kills the undo function, and you have to be careful with multicell and multiarea inserts/copies etc.

Comment: but i will be doing this mutiple time and on new worksheet each time...so setting the conditional formatting can be quite a chore...was thinking of doing a marco so that it can be done with a press of a button

Comment: @Nelson ALthough I have submitted an edit, Stack Overflow isn't a 'write this code for me' site. You might want to look at `Hackhands`, which offers coding support for $1/minute (some Stack Overflow users are on here, too).

Comment: thks cybermonkey and keku